# LibGDX - how to scale art work with the camera?

Tags: libgdx

I've been reading about `OrthographicCamera` but I'm not sure if I'm using it right with my art assests.
Let me just start by saying that all my art is meant for an iphone5 display (1136*640).
Now, I'm using 2 `OrthographicCamera`s

1. Size of 5meters*5meters - this camera is following my main character in a game.
2. Size of 800px*640px - this camera is used to render stuff on the screen like score, lives etc..

Now I'm trying to use the first camera to render my art, so for example I have a png image,
how do I know how to scale it according to my defined camera (remember, it's 5m*5m)?
I cannot just say it's 1m (1/5 of the world size) since the image looks bad, I want to keep it in it's original size and let the framework scale it according to the phone size.

My current code is something like:

```
OrthographicCamera worldCamera; // 5 meters * 5 meters
OrthographicCamera sceneCamera; // 800px*640px
SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void render() {
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(sceneCamera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    //render background using Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and Gdx.graphics.getHeight()
    batch.end();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(sceneCamera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    //render "static" elements, score lives etc..
    batch.end();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(worldCamera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    //render "movable" elements - how do I scale them here? I want their original size!
    batch.end();
}
```